# java spring rest parameter not work

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, parameter-passing

I created code where pass data to spring rest but don't work correctly see my code below:

```
@PutMapping("/notification/save/{id}")
public @ResponseBody String update(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody  AccountNotification accountNotification){
    String result="ok";
    ServiceAccount serviceAccount =  new ServiceAccount();
    serviceAccount.setId(id);
    //accountNotification.setServiceAccount( serviceAccount );
    //result =notificationsService.update(id,accountNotification);

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
             JSONObject accountNotificationJSON = new JSONObject();

             if(result.equals("ok")) {
                 accountNotificationJSON.put("success", "true");
                 accountNotificationJSON.put("messages", "Successfully Saved");
             }
             else {
                 accountNotificationJSON.put("success", "false");
                 accountNotificationJSON.put("messages", "NOT Successfully Saved");

             }
             jArray.put(accountNotificationJSON);

        jObject.put("data", jArray);
    } catch (JSONException jse) {
        logger.error( jse.getMessage());
    }


    return jObject.toString();
}
```

my javascrit has:

```
$("#saveChanges").on('click',function(){
     var params1={
             proxy:$(proxy).val() ,
             port:$(port).val(),
             uri:$(uri).val(),
             actived:$(actived).val()=="on"?true:false
     };

     $.ajax({
         url: 'notification/save/'+id,
         params: params1,
         type: 'post',
         success:function(response) {
             if(response.data[0].success == "true") {                      
                 $(".removeMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                      '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.data[0].messages+
                     '</div>');


                 // close the modal
                 $("#editMember").modal('hide');

             } else {
                 $(".removeMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                      '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.data[0].messages+
                     '</div>');
             }
         },
         error: function(x, e) {
                alert(x);
              }

     });
```

in this situation ajax code return 400. Any body knows why? thanks if withdraw @RequestBody annotation the rest has been called but the parameter accountNotifications is initialized but without valeus passed.

Comment: Change `PutMapping` to`RequestMapping`

Comment: dont work to, I had tryed before this mode : @RequestMapping(value={"/notification/save/{id}"},produces = "application/json", method= {RequestMethod.POST})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this mode:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/notification/save/{id}"},  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST},
         produces = "application/json"

        )
public @ResponseBody String update(@PathVariable("id") long id, AccountNotification accountNotification){
    String result="ok";
```

JavaScript:

```html
 $("#saveChanges").on('click',function(){
   var params1={
     proxy:$(proxy).val() ,
     port:$(port).val(),
     uri:$(uri).val(),
     actived:$(actived).is(':checked')
   };
   
         $.ajax({
             url: 'notification/save/'+id,
             data: params1,
             type: 'post',
             success:function(response) {
```

I replaced into js param with data

Answer (score 1):

there is a put mapping `@PutMapping("/notification/save/{id}")` in your Rest code, but in your js called by post method `type: 'post',` so it returns 400 `Bad Request`, you should use `type: put` which is equals to your Rest method.

```
 @PutMapping("/notification/save/{id}")
 public @ResponseBody String update(@PathVariable("id") long id, 
 @RequestParam  AccountNotification accountNotification){
 .....
 }



  $.ajax({
     url: 'notification/save/'+id,
     params: params1,
     type: 'put',
     success:function(){
 }})
```

Comment: {"timestamp":1511437558654,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String br.com.supportcomm.trust.web.NotificationController.update(long,br.com.supportcomm.trust.model.AccountNotification)","path":"/next-trust/notification/save/4"}

Comment: can you able to post your  `AccountNotification` class

Comment: you don't send a body (data parameter in JQuery)

Comment: There is a mismatch between your entity class parameters and data which you are sending through ajax request.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli mentioned correctly  you should use `@RequestParam` annotations